# How to prevent flash of text when using <noscript> alternatives

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, noscript

I am working on a chunk of legacy code for an in-house intranet application that relies on Javascript. I am aware and agree that progressive enhancement and unobtrusive Javascript practices are the preferred approach rather than to rely on it and simply issue a warning to the user if not support for it is available, but this is an in-house legacy application that does not justify the cost of refactoring.

Lately I have run into a few problems with the `<noscript>` tag, mostly in the form of incorrect markup and styling on some platforms. Recognizing the fact that there is at least talk of making `<noscript>` a candidate for deprecation and that behavior and styling do not belong in HTML in the first place, I have looked into alternatives.

My first approach was to replace

```
<noscript>La di da</noscript>
```

with

```
<span class="noScript">La di da</span>
```

and some jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.noScript').css('display', 'none');
}
```

This works, but since jQuery has to load along with everything else before `$(document).ready()` will fire, there is a delay during which the noscript alternative content is visible.

I then replaced the above jQuery code with "old school" Javascript included at the very end of the page (right before `</body></html>`):

```
document.getElementById("noScript").style.display = "none";
```

This works a lot better, but there is still a short delay which causes the noscript content to flash across the screen before being rendered invisible by the Javascript code.

How to prevent this flash of content? Or is there a better way to deal with this? (Other than to refactor all legacy code so as not to require Javascript other than for enhancements, that is, since I do not have that option available to me.)

Comment: We have dealt with this wrapping the content inside the <noscript> tag with a container set to display: none by default, then detect if scripts are not available and then show the content. <noscript><span style="display:none;">La di da</span></noscript>

Comment: @EgilHansen *then show the content* - this question is exactly: how do you do that?

Comment: *making <noscript> a candidate for deprecation* - do you have any evidence of this?  Seems like something that you shouldn't be worrying about - there's "talk" of making computers deprecated... in maybe 200-300 years...   Quick search came up with:  https://www.w3.org/html/wg/tracker/issues/117  from 2010, which was closed